# How to map object of nested arrays in react native

Tags: javascript, mapping, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a `data.json` file :

```
{
    "category1":[
    {"name":"XYZ","price":100,"instock":true},
    {"name":"ABC","price":934,"instock":false},
    {"name":"OTR","price":945,"instock":true},
    {"name":"SLG","price":343,"instock":true},
    {"name":"KGN","price":342,"instock":true},
    {"name":"GDS","price":234,"instock":true},
    {"name":"KNL","price":934,"instock":true},
    {"name":"GLM","price":320,"instock":true},
    {"name":"DKF","price":394,"instock":false},
    {"name":"VFS","price":854,"instock":true}
    ],
    "category2":[
    {"name":"NA","price":124,"instock":true},
    {"name":"DS","price":953,"instock":true},
    {"name":"HF","price":100,"instock":true},
    {"name":"FJ","price":583,"instock":true},
    {"name":"LS","price":945,"instock":false},
    {"name":"TR","price":394,"instock":true},
    {"name":"PD","price":35,"instock":true},
    {"name":"AL","price":125,"instock":true},
    {"name":"TK","price":129,"instock":true},
    {"name":"PG","price":294,"instock":true}
    ]
}
```

I am storing all these data in my reducer of redux and then using hooks to store in my state:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState({});
setItems(createMenuReducer.data.menu)
console.log(items);
```

when console my `items` I get the following output:

```
{cat1: Array(10), cat2: Array(10), default: {…}}
cat1: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
cat2: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
default: {cat1: Array(10), cat2: Array(10)}
__proto__: Object
```

I want to map through this `items` and display the `name` and `price` on the screen.

```
{
    createMenuReducer &&
    items?.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <Text>item</Text>
        );
    })
}
```

But I am getting error: `items.map is not a function`.

I know my way of mapping is wrong, But I always gets confused when mapping something. Please someone explain me how I can display name and price with their category names i.e. `category1` and `category2`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that *.map* is a function of the array object and you are currently handling a javascript object with key pair values in your items object.

The easiest way to go about doing what you are trying to do would be to say

```
for(let key in items){
    items[key].map( item => {
       console.log(item.name + " : " + item.price);
    })
}
```

Comment: Both `item.name` and `item.price` is coming in console, but when everything is printed there is an error message `items[key].map is not a function`

Comment: Most likely it is caused by the default key. Looking at the case at hand i think the easiest way would be if you added if( Array.isArray( items[key] )){...}. around the map statement

Comment: There is no output in console

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use `Array.map` on `objects`, you'll first have to transform that data. [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) could be useful in your case. You could use it to get all of the `values` from the `keys` in your `object` and then concatenate the arrays into a single one using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Here's an example of how it can be done:

```js
const data = {
  "category1": [{
      "name": "XYZ",
      "price": 100,
      "instock": true
    },
    {
      "name": "ABC",
      "price": 934,
      "instock": false
    },
    {
      "name": "OTR",
      "price": 945,
      "instock": true
    },
    {
      "name": "SLG",
      "price": 343,
      "instock": true
    },
    {
      "name": "KGN",
      "price": 342,
      "instock": true
    },
    {
      "name": "GDS",
      "price": 234,
      "instock": true
    },
    {
      "name": "KNL",
      "price": 934,
      "instock": true
    },
    {
      "name": "GLM",
      "price": 320,
      "instock": true
    },
    {
      "name": "DKF",
      "price": 394,
      "instock": false
    },
    {
      "name": "VFS",
      "price": 854,
      "instock": true
    }
  ],
  "category2": [{
      "name": "NA",
      "price": 124,
      "instock": true
    },
    {
      "name": "DS",
      "price": 953,
      "instock": true
    },
    {
      "name": "HF",
      "price": 100,
      "instock": true
    },
    {
      "name": "FJ",
      "price": 583,
      "instock": true
    },
    {
      "name": "LS",
      "price": 945,
      "instock": false
    },
    {
      "name": "TR",
      "price": 394,
      "instock": true
    },
    {
      "name": "PD",
      "price": 35,
      "instock": true
    },
    {
      "name": "AL",
      "price": 125,
      "instock": true
    },
    {
      "name": "TK",
      "price": 129,
      "instock": true
    },
    {
      "name": "PG",
      "price": 294,
      "instock": true
    }
  ]
};

const final = Object
  .values(data)
  .reduce((arr, nextArr) => [...arr, ...nextArr], []);

console.log(final);
```